# What happens to the level of water when ice containing stone melts?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

> What would happen to the level of water in a vessel, when ice containing a stone, melts?

If there was no stone, the level of water will not change. But when the ice contains a stone inside it melts, would the level of water change?

(The ice is floating initially and the stone sinks after the ice melts)

(The stone has a finite volume less than that of the ice)

Comment: This really belongs in  puzzles.SE, or whatever the site name is.  But first clarify: is the ice floating or has the stone forced the block of ice to the bottom?  What is the density of the stone (pumice floats :-) ).  And BTW, if you have ice floating in water, when the ice melts, the water level **will change** . Think about it.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I edited the question

Answer (score 2):

The water level remains constant if the object keeps floating on it as it melts. You can show that easily mathematically, with the help of Archimedes's law. As ice melts, the volume the block displaces decreases, but then water from the ice compensates as it joins the water. If there is a stone in the ice however, then at a certain point the ice + stone will be more dense than water and it will sink. You can imagine, the ice surrounding the stone under water melts and takes up less place, meaning that the water level decreases.